# Getting *NIC info from remote machines on network?

Tags: powershell, nic

so I'm a systems engineer and am trying to make my job a little easier. Our scripter here doesn't have the time to get to me because he's often very busy so I was hoping someone here could help me out. I know a little powershell but not to the extent I'm trying to use it.

What I'm attempting to do is use a predefined list of IP addresses and get all network interface card information from them. I tried writing a couple scripts myself, however they messed some stuff up so that wouldn't fly. I bought a script, but it only does 1 machine at a time and takes about 2 minutes per machine. I basically need an autonomous script that will do this and output the information so I can give it my network guys.

I'm not asking for someone to write the entire script, but rather give me some guidance or a couple examples?

Here's what I have. I want to make it read from a file though and just do it autonomously.

http://pastebin.com/dVEDM4Kd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to iterate your current script through a list of IPs, you need to wrap the script in a ForEach loop, then at end of the script pipe that object out to a text file.

To load the IP addresses from a text file, just create a new file with **one** IP per line and use Get-Content to load the file into the script for use.

You will need to change the top of your script like so,

```
 #This is the file where your IP or Computernames will go.
    $IPAddresses = Get-Content 'c:\test\servers.txt'


    $myCol = @()

    # this Foreach will take each item that is in $ipaddresses and assign them to 
    # $servername one at a time and run the code within the block for each item in 
    # IPAddresses.  $servername was the var name already so I just rolled with it

   ForEach($servername in $IPAddresses){

    $NicConfig = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $serverName


    ForEach ($Nic in $NicConfig)
```

and at the end to send all that collected data out to a file just alter the last line like so:

```
    $myCol | Out-file 'C:\test\Outfile.txt'
```

Since it was pretty straight forward, I went ahead and created a copy of your script with the changes.  This might meet your needs but if not it should get you started.

http://pastebin.com/HY9e5x1V

Comment: I added and tweaked your version of the script several times. I keep getting errors. I'm not sure why you're using the $servername in IPAddresses when you haven't defined the variable $servername. I'm trying to understand it, but I'm a little confused?
I'm only attempting to acquire the NIC description and model. This script was bought and it has way too much info. I tried to dumb down the script and I had it working before, but your changing of the beginning of the script is a little confusing. Could you explain to me perhaps what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? The original script you had on pastebin threw some strange errors for me with trying to access some subkeys. but that was outside the scope of this question and I didn't know if it was a permissions issue on my end. I will add comments to the script in the above answer for clarity.

Comment: Ok so here is what I have the script down to now.
http://pastebin.com/4ZBLAY0A

I really only need the description and model. Thats all I'm trying to display, however if you create a "call file" and use it on your machine it for some reason won't give me the NICModel and repeats the process four times. I'm not sure if this is just because Its on my end. If you can see something that I'm doing wrong here let me know. I sometimes have to get close to 800 servers *NIC information for the network engineers here and past methods are too slow.

Comment: Any help will be MUCH appreciated, I'm still learning and LOVE powershell.

Comment: You have gutted too much of the logic out of that script for it to work.  But again, that is outside the scope of this question.  You should mark this one as answered if it is and then submit your next question.